# SQL tag hint needs `sqlite` added as a possible database engine

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

When you tag a question with `sqlite` and `sql`, you're still prompted that you should add a tag for a particular database engine.  I'm guessing that `sqlite` is simply absent from whatever list drives this UI.

[image: Screenshot of tag hint]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning shown reminds you of several things, not just to include what database you are using. As such it is shown regardless of what database engine tags you used.

So no, there is no bug here. SQLite is not special, the warning won’t go away when you use any of the other database engine tags either.